# Looking for explanation with a Kotlin non-null assertion error in Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I am writing an Android application but I receive the following compiler warning depicted in the screenshot.

My question about this particular error pertains to the following lines:

```
if (months?.toInt() == 1) { monthsText = "1 Mo " }
if (months?.toInt() > 1) { monthsText = String.format("%d Mos ", months) }
```

The first line with == compiles fine but > 1 produces the null assertion.  I have added a screenshot of the error and a code snippet.  BTW, if there is a better way to code that it may be helpful in my understanding of the issue.

If I add the !! as noted in the error, it compiles and runs, but if the months var is null, which it may be the app crashes.

I don't really understand why == would be different than >

[image]

The database I am getting this data from has the "yearsMonthsExperience" stored as "1205" (YYMM).

```
val yearsMonths= (markerData.mMarkerUser!!["yearsMonthsExperience"] as? String)?.padStart(4, '0')
val years = yearsMonths?.take(2)?.toInt()
val months = yearsMonths?.takeLast(2)?.toInt()
var yearsText = ""
if (years != null && years == 1) { yearsText = "1 Yr " }
if (years != null && years > 1) { yearsText = String.format("%d Yrs ", years) }
var monthsText = ""
if (months?.toInt() == 1) { monthsText = "1 Mo " }
if (months?.toInt() > 1) { monthsText = String.format("%d Mos ", months) }
mInfoView.lbYearsExperience.text = String.format("%s%s Exp.", yearsText, monthsText)
```

Thanks in advance for any explanation or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` is an overriden operator. It is only syntactic sugar.

So your if statement actually looks like this: `months?.toInt().compareTo(1)`

To make it work you need to give it a default value something like this: `months?.toInt()?:0 > 1`.

You can read more about operator overloading here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html

Comment: Ahhh, I see, thank you so much.   And YES, I will definitely read up more on it.  I did not know you could put a default value before the operator.

Comment: `??` is actually Dart syntax ups. I have corrected it to `?:`. `?:` is called the Elvis operator and you can give a default value to any `null` value.

Comment: Lol, yes, I realized that and updated my comment to you. Thanks again I am familiar with the Elvis operator.

Comment: Happy to help, please do not forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I will, I did!!  Thanks again!!